# Cards and metrics dissapeared from Laravel Nova default dashboard

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm using Laravel Framework 8.9.0 with Nova 3.12

Yesterday, I was succesfully working with some metrics and cards in the default dashboard, but today they are missing.

I've been moving back throught commits, but they doesn't show. Surely it's an stupid issue, but I cant achieve the answer.

The cards and the metrics are on the novaServiceProvider, but I'm unable to get why they are missing. I've cleaned cache, reinstalled npm and composer, but it's still broken.

Did you ever had this kind of issue before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I just had to publish Nova again:

```
php artisan nova:publish
```

And after that, update composer:

```
composer update
```